# TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable (Error with delete_one)

Tags: python, mongodb, delete, collection, validationerror

Este código iba perfectamente.
Se accede a una colección de la base de datos de Mongo, se extraen los datos y se eliminan los más antiguos.
Sin embargo, desde hace una semana, aunque puedo acceder a los datos, filtrarlos y mostrarlos, no puedo eliminarlos por que me dice que `delete_one` no es un método de "Collection"
La base de datos está activa (Se usa un docker-compose) y, como comento, es que se puede acceder a los datos y a cada minuto que pasa se añaden nuvos datos (Documentos en este caso)

```
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient

with MongoClient(MONGODB_URI) as client:  # MongoDB
   
    db = client['twitter_raw']

    tweets_collection = db['tweets_venezuela']

    # number of documents in the collection
    mydoc = tweets_collection.find().count()
    print("The number of documents in collection : ", mydoc) 
    print(tweets_collection)

    #tweets_collection.delete_one({'created_at':"2022-03-01 04:12:22"})
    # print(tweets_collection.find_one())
    for row in tweets_collection.find({}):
        fecha = row["created_at"]
        if(str(fecha) < "2022-02-17 04:12:22"):
            tweets_collection.delete_one({'created_at':fecha})
        else:
            print(fecha)
```

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando? Es bastante raro y no encuentro nada por internet
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué librería usas para mongodb? Agrega los imports, please.

Comment: Ya las he añadido. Pero sólo MongoClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto. El problema era que `pymongo` se ejecuta en un `pipenv` y ahí, no se había actualizado la librería, por lo que estaba todo perfecto. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

El código que presentas tiene varios problemas que trataré de exponer en mi respuesta.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea eliminar selectivamente basado en una propiedad de tipo `Date` los documentos de una colección de MongoDB que superen el filtro establecido.

Los problemas con el código presentado son varios, los cuales enumero a continuación:

1. Se realizan llamadas a la base de datos de forma innecesaria para obtener el número de documentos y luego para obtener nuevamente los documentos de la colección y para eliminar uno a uno los documentos que no superan el filtro:

Primera llamada:

```py
# number of documents in the collection
mydoc = tweets_collection.find().count()
print("The number of documents in collection : ", mydoc)
```

Segunda llamada:

```py
for row in tweets_collection.find({}):
   ...
```

Múltiples llamadas:

```py
fecha = row["created_at"]
if(str(fecha) < "2022-02-17 04:12:22"):
    tweets_collection.delete_one({'created_at':fecha})
```

2. La conversión del tipo `datetime.datetime` a una cadena no es necesaria:

```py
fecha = row["created_at"]
if(str(fecha) < "2022-02-17 04:12:22"):
   ...
```

3. Usas un método obsoleto (*deprecated*) para obtener la cantidad de documentos de la colección (`count`). Claro está que podrías estar usando una versión muy antigua del driver de conexión o del mismo Python.

```py
# number of documents in the collection
mydoc = tweets_collection.find().count()  # <- DEPRECATED
```

4. Usas `delete_one` pasando como filtro un campo de fecha que puede o no devolver un resultado, además que no te garantiza que elimina el documento al que apunta `row`, sino que elimina el primero que encuentre usando ese filtro:

```py
tweets_collection.delete_one({'created_at':fecha})
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar la tarea que te has propuesto hay que solucionar los problemas citados anteriormente, primero nos enfocaremos en la cantidad de llamadas a la base de datos.

Supongamos que tu colección tiene cientos de miles de documentos, lo típico de una base de datos que almacena *tweets*. Si nos enfocamos en lo que estás haciendo actualmente tenemos lo siguiente:

- Cuento los documentos de la colección usando `count`, que hace un conteo de todos los documentos recorriendo la colección completa.
- Recorro la colección y si encuentro un documento que no pasa el filtro lo elimino (pero no elimino **ese** documento, sino que el primero cuyo valor `created_at` sea igual al valor de `fecha`), siendo esta consulta bastante ambigua, ya que podría darse el caso de más de un documento con el mismo valor para `created_at`. ¿Cuál estoy eliminando?
- Si la colección tiene cientos de miles de documentos y muchos de esos cientos de miles superan el filtro, estoy llamando a la base de datos cientos de miles de veces para eliminar 1 documento cada vez.

Esto es bastante ineficiente e impráctico, además, si tu DB es de pago (MongoAtlas por ejemplo) el costo por cada operación de escritura suma.

Supongamos que no son cientos de miles de documentos y puedo permitirme el costo de enviar algunas decenas de consultas, aunque siga siendo ineficiente, el código se podría ver así:

```py
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
MONGO_DB = 'twitter_raw'
COLLECTION = 'tweets_venezuela'
# equivalente a "2022-02-17 04:12:22.000"
fecha = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 4, 12, 22, 0)

with MongoClient(MONGO_URI) as client:
    db = client[MONGO_DB]                       # Base de Datos
    coll = db[COLLECTION]                       # Colección
    n_docs = coll.estimated_document_count({})  # Documentos actuales
    print(f'Cantidad de documentos: {n_docs}')
    count = 0
    for doc in coll.find({}):                   # Recorremos la colección
        if doc['created_at'] < fecha:
            coll.delete_one(
              {'_id': doc['_id']}               # Borrado por _id
            )
            count += 1
        else:
            print(doc['created_at'])            # Mostramos la fecha

    print(f'Documentos eliminados: {count}')    # Resultado
    print(                                      # Documentos después de eliminar
        f'Documentos actualmente en la colección: {collection.estimated_document_count({})}')
```

El código anterior se apega al planteamiento original excepto que se usa el método [`estimated_document_count`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.estimated_document_count) que es mucho más eficiente para determinar la cantidad de documentos de una colección.

Además, para eliminar el documento que no supera el filtro, utilizo su campo `_id` en vez del campo `created_at`, para evitar así la ambigüedad de la consulta, ya que el campo `_id` es único, pero el campo `created_at` no lo es.

Por otro lado, la comparación `doc['created_at'] < fecha` se hace entre objetos [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), lo que hace innecesario convertir el valor a su representación de cadena.

**Mejora**

Como he dicho anteriormente, el código anterior no es performante, es decir, podemos mejorarlo. El asunto es evitar múltiples llamados a base de datos y realizar la operación en una sola llamada. ¿Cómo lo hacemos?.

Si analizamos detenidamente lo que estamos haciendo, nos damos cuenta que estamos eliminando cada documento de la colección cuyo campo `created_at` tenga un valor inferior a un parámetro dado (`fecha`). En vez de ir uno por uno a través de los documentos de la colección, usando [`delete_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.delete_one), podemos decirle a MongoDB que elimine directamente todos los documentos que existan en la colección, cuyo campo `created_at` sea menor que `fecha`. Para ello podemos usar [`delete_many`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.delete_many).

Al método `delete_many` debemos pasarle el filtro de búsqueda, el cual es un diccionario que contendrá el campo a evaluar y cuyo valor será a su vez otro diccionario que contendrá el [operador de consulta `$lt`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) como clave y la variable `fecha` como valor, por ejemplo:

```py
filter = {'created_at': { '$lt': fecha } }
```

De esta forma, MongoDB eliminará todos los documentos de la colección que coincidan con el filtro de búsqueda, en una sola llamada a la base de datos. El código podría verse parecido al siguiente:

```py
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
MONGO_DB = 'twitter_raw'
COLLECTION = 'tweets_venezuela'
# equivalente a "2022-02-17 04:12:22.000"
fecha = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 4, 12, 22, 0)
filter = {'created_at': {'$lt': fecha}}

with MongoClient(MONGO_URI) as client:
    db = client[MONGO_DB]
    coll = db[COLLECTION]
    print(f'Cantidad de documentos: {coll.estimated_document_count({})}')
    result = coll.delete_many(filter)
    print(f'Documentos eliminados: {result.deleted_count}')
```

Como puedes observar, hemos reducido solo a 2 llamadas a la base de datos para realizar la misma tarea.

Aún si deseas mostrar las fechas de los documentos, una vez realizada la eliminación, sería una llamada adicional a la base de datos donde simplemente vas a recorrer los elementos de la colección para mostrar la fecha.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola Mauricio. Gracias por el tiempo empleado en intentar ayudarme. Sólo hay un registro con la misma fecha, puesto que se guardan tweets cada dos minutos, no obstante, tienes razón. Sólamente habrá 720 tweets (Porque cada día se eliminan los datos, puesto que pasan a almacenarse con un proceso de lasificación en una postgres.) El problema. es que a pesar de lo que me has pasado, sigue sin encontrarme la función ```delete_many```, pero el ```find``` para mostrar los valores sí... De todas formas, mañana probaré de nuevo a ver que ocurre... Es como si al entrar al ```for```

Comment: Efectivamente, aunque tu código se ve más correcto (Aunque no es parte de la aplicación sino de un archivo de pruebas para ver errores) Sigue sin encontrar las funciones y me da el mismo error que con mi código

Comment: Verifica la versión de PyMongo instalada y la versión de Python también

Comment: Ambos están en la última versión. La verdad es que es muy raro jjeje